# Postgres streaming replication - servers keep shutting down

Tags: postgresql, streaming, replication

I am new to PostgreSQL and I am trying to set up a streaming replication from our server to a test DB on my laptop. I have been following this tutorial https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/09/07/setting-up-streaming-replication-postgresql/ along with the Postgres documentation here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-replication.html.

I'm running Windows 10, PostgreSQL 11, PostGIS 2.5 extension.

The server and my local machine both keep shutting down and the logs are filled with postmaster.pid errors such as:

```
LOG: performing immediate shutdown because data directory lock file is invalid
LOG: received immediate shutdown request
LOG: could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
```

Could anyone point me towards the issue here? I know my server's aren't configured properly but I just don't know what configurations need to be changed.

Here is an image of my standby server's most recent log.
[standby log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nrul.jpg)
Here is an image of my master server's most recent log. 
[master log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX4VZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must have messed up in many ways.

- You removed or overwrote `postmaster.pid` on the master server.

  That is very dangerous and causes the server to die with the error message you quote.
- You didn't create `recovery.conf` before starting the standby server, or you removed `backup_label`. From the error messages I'd suspect the second, with ensuing data corruption.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I suppose at this point I just need a fresh install of PostgreSQL on both machines. Luckily this is just a test environment!